# Python Solution - Exporting Microsoft BI sheets to excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export, powerbi

Apologize if this is simple, but documentation on using Python with Microsoft BI is sparse at best.  I'm curious if there is a command that imports Microsoft BI files similar to the read_excel function in pandas.

I have a Microsoft BI file that has 175 worksheets, each of which is currently being exported to excel and saved by hand each day.  Looking for some way to automate, and thought that if I could essentially read each file into Python and then save as an excel file it would save a tremendous amount of time.

Also adding a note that I prefer to save as csv as opposed to xlsx.

Comment: Are they 175 distinct sheets? Just wondering if python could skip the BI piece to get them into Excel files?

Comment: Yes, each is a distinct sheet in BI.  Something is calculated in BI each day so they can't be converted to skip the BI portion.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the structure of each sheet? Is there just a single visual on each sheet? It is likely easier to just query the data model (e.g. with [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.org/)) and save the results to a file and deal with them from there.

Comment: As I said its pretty complicated so I don't really know the guts at all.  Would a screenshot give you the insight you're looking for?  It might also be useful to note that I am currently using the "Export data" function on each tab to save to csv.

Answer (score 1):

From within PowerBI you basically have two options. I don't think there is any possibility to import a PowerBI file into Python.

1. Inside PowerQuery you add Run Python Script as step to your transformation (Transform menu > Run Python Script). This allows you to use Python in the way you are used to and makes sure all data before this step is moved into a dataframe called dataset. You can simply use *dataset.to_excel()* to store this dataset as Excel file. Be sure to change the working directory with something like *os.chdir()* becasue by default it is running in a temporary directory.
2. Inside PowerBI you can add a script visual. Although it says it requires visual output of your script, the reality is that any code is executed even if the script does not result in a rendered image. The same principal hold as mentioned for the step from PowerQuery. Use *os.chdir()* to specify your directory and use *dataset.to_excel()* to export.

For both make sure Python scripting is enabled in the options, should be by default when you have python installed on your machine, else have a look through the menu, you'll easily find it.

Comment: Any chance you could give a code example for this answer? Let's say I have a BI file called File1, with tabs labeled TabA and TabB.  And I wanted to save them in a folder called Tabs as C:\Tabs\Tab1 and C:\Tabs\Tab2

Comment: I can probably advise you on that. Can you give a bit more insight into your Power BI file? Like what does the data model look like? How many tables do you have? What transformations are done in Power BI and what kind of analsys do you do on the data? What do you mean with the 175 tabs? Sounds like a pretty big and slow Power BI file in that case. What's the reasoning behind it? This problem comes down entirely to efficiency. With some smart choices along the way, I believe the export via Python can be quite easy.

Comment: Jelle, thanks for the help.  I deliberately left it a bit vague in hopes of coming up with a solution based on just that.  This is because I am painfully unfamiliar with BI.  While much of the work done in this sheet would have been easier in Python, the creator chose BI for its compression (and is not a Python user). It is both large and slow.  As far as 175 tabs, the file literally appears with 175 sheets at the bottom that I would consider equivalent to excel worksheets, my only task is to save each one (after a daily data refresh) with its appropriate name as a csv file.

Comment: Well the Python solution I proposed could work but still requires you to click through the 175 sheets individually. To be honest, hearing the way this was set-up, the only efficient way is to completely remodel and use Python as a data processor and have it perform the analysis. Nothing it can't do that Power BI can. Start by editing the Query to so the origin of the data.